# Segmentation fault (strcat_sse2_unaligned) while calling a function

Tags: c, gtk, strcat

I have a function:

```
//In main.c    
char output_entry () {
  extern  FILE* yyin;
  extern int yyparse (void);
  yyin=fmemopen(buffer,strlen(buffer),"r");
  return yyparse();
}
```

which works fine when called from

```
//Open file
gchar *filename;
void open_file(GtkWidget *widget, gpointer data)
{
  GError* error=NULL;
  GtkWidget *dialog;
  GtkFileFilter *filter;
  dialog = gtk_file_chooser_dialog_new("Open File", NULL,
      GTK_FILE_CHOOSER_ACTION_OPEN,
      GTK_STOCK_OPEN, GTK_RESPONSE_ACCEPT,
      GTK_STOCK_CANCEL, GTK_RESPONSE_CANCEL,
      NULL);
  filter = gtk_file_filter_new();
  gtk_file_filter_set_name(filter, "All files (*.*)");
  gtk_file_filter_add_pattern(filter, "*");
  gtk_file_chooser_add_filter(GTK_FILE_CHOOSER(dialog), filter);

  filter = gtk_file_filter_new();
  gtk_file_filter_set_name(filter, "Bibtex file (*.bib)");
  gtk_file_filter_add_pattern(filter, "*.bib");
  gtk_file_chooser_add_filter(GTK_FILE_CHOOSER(dialog), filter);
  gtk_file_chooser_set_filter(GTK_FILE_CHOOSER(dialog), filter);

  if (gtk_dialog_run(GTK_DIALOG(dialog)) == GTK_RESPONSE_ACCEPT)
  {
    gtk_list_store_clear (store);
    filename = gtk_file_chooser_get_filename(GTK_FILE_CHOOSER(dialog));
    g_file_get_contents(filename, &buffer, &length , &error);
    g_assert(!error);
    buf_mod=FALSE;

    char* markup=g_markup_printf_escaped ("<span style=\"italic\">%s</span>", filename);
    gtk_label_set_markup(GTK_LABEL(flabel), markup);
    gtk_widget_destroy(dialog); 

    output_entry();
  }
  else{
    gtk_widget_destroy(dialog);
//    g_free(buffer);
  }
}
```

This is standard method of opening a file. and `buffer` is

```
//in main.h
extern gchar *buffer;
```

and initialized in main.c (as adviced [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17054979/program-givin-error-when-gchar-is-initialized))

This part of the code is working fine.
I tried to use output_entry with some other source as well:

```
void gs_open(GtkWidget *window, gpointer data) {
  GScanner *gs_scanner;
  GHashTable *gs_table;
  GError* error=NULL;
  GtkTextIter start, end;
  GtkListStore *gs_store;
  GtkTreeIter siter;
  GtkWidget *gs_tree;
  gboolean valid;
  GString *ustring = g_string_new ("");
  GString *str=g_string_new(NULL);

  GtkTextBuffer *gs_buf=gtk_text_view_get_buffer(GTK_TEXT_VIEW(gs_txt));
  gtk_text_buffer_get_start_iter (gs_buf, &start);
  gtk_text_buffer_get_end_iter (gs_buf, &end);
  gchar *gs_text = gtk_text_buffer_get_text (gs_buf, &start, &end, FALSE);
  strcat(buffer, gs_text);
  gtk_list_store_clear(store);
  output_entry ();
  buf_mod=TRUE;
  gtk_widget_destroy(gtk_widget_get_toplevel (window));
}
```

And this gives seg fault. Running with gdb shows:

```
Using host libthread_db library "/lib64/libthread_db.so.1".
[New Thread 0x7ffff16fc700 (LWP 6178)]

Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x0000003b94097261 in __strcat_sse2_unaligned () from /lib64/libc.so.6
```

Kindly help (I am a novice in C). And google is not helping much on the `strcat_sse2_unaligned`

**EDIT 2**

```
 up
#1  0x0000000000407195 in gs_open (window=0x863a80, data=<optimized out>)
    at src/search.c:103
103   strcat(buffer, gs_text);
```

Comment: `strcat()` is not magic, you need to allocate a **big enough** and **writable** buffer for it.

Comment: Look at the backtrace when the crash happens, it's done using the `bt` command in GDB. Then walk up the callstack (using the `up` command) until you come to your code. Then examine the variables there, or at least edit your question to show where in your code that is.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg

Kindly have a look at edited post.

Comment: buffer is Pointer to the destination array, which should contain a C string, and be large enough to contain the concatenated resulting string.

Comment: I dont understand, but I am suspicious if size of the `buffer` is problem here. I can open `a.txt` using `open_file`, which is 8KB, but get the sag fault when trying to open `b.txt` which is 4KB using `gs_open`

Answer (score 2):

I don't really see anywhere where you *allocate* memory for `buffer`. This means that it's a `NULL` pointer (as it's a global variable). You have to allocate memory for the buffer before you can use it.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you're trying to use `strlen()` to compute the size of a buffer, rather than the length of a string.

If `buffer` doesn't contain a valid 0-terminated string, you can't use `strlen()` on it. It will likely step out of valid memory, and (most importantly) generate a result which is not at all what you need.

You should probably have a separate variable holding the size of the buffer pointed at by  `buffer`.

Answer (score 0):

the `strcat` line is replaced by:

```
  if (buffer == NULL){
    buffer=g_strdup(gs_text);
  }
  else{
    gchar *t=buffer;
    buffer=g_strconcat(buffer,gs_text,NULL);
    g_free(t);
  }
```

which has solve the problem.

Looking forward for comments.

Comment: *t = buffer does not allocate new memory. It just makes t point to buffer. When you free(t) the memory block as you do in the last line, you actually freeing buffer, which probably is not exactly what you want to.